# SugarCRM: How to get the id of a dashlet (not dashboard) in the dashlet controller .js file?

Tags: sugarcrm

I am accessing `this.model.attributes` and it returns

```
{
  "id": "suihio-32b3-432jk4-43n" // This is the Dashboard id
  "dashboard_name": "Test Dashboard",
  "metadata": {
    "dashlets": [
      {"id": "23434-34234f-34ffkke-jnsd", "name": "Test dashlet 1", ...},
      {"id": "bsdu7svs-v34343f4w-4f34f4-4f43", "name": "Test dashlet 2", ...},
      ...
    ]
  }
}
```

I am unable to get the dashlet id in the dashlet controller `.js` file. Always, I have to filter using the name of the dashlet within the `metadata->dashlets` array, so facing issue when multiple dashlets are there with same name.

I want to know how I can get the particular dashlet id from the controller `.js` file.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching in millions of places, finally I found a solution. The is is not there in any property of the `this` object. But it is placed in the dashlet container layout div as a data attribute.

We need to use

```
var dashletId = this.layout.el.dataset.gsId;
```

to get the id. But if we query it directly inside the controller, it will provide us `undefined` as the html is not rendered till now. We have to add a timeout before querying the same as below.

```
setTimeout(_.bind(function () {
    var dashletId = this.layout.el.dataset.gsId;
    this.render();
}, this), 0);
```